# App crashes on this.getWritableDatabase();

Tags: java, android

The following code is a function in my dbhandler. This works fine on android studio emulator but crashes on my actual mobile. If I comment out the line `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` then it works fine. What would cause this?

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getCategories(int ParID){
    ArrayList<Integer> catAr  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    catAr.add(1);

    //loop thru all cats and store id's in catAr
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    db.close();
    return catAr;
}
```

Comment: Please upload whole class file

Comment: Post your LogCat message too.

Comment: What was the `Context` you passed to this `SQLiteOpenHelper` in constructor?

Comment: I've managed to overcome this problem now. It seems that once the dbhandler instance has been created android (4.4 in my case) doesn't like to keep closing and re-opening the db in each function of the class. So I removed db.close() from all functions and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm if the DB exists or not. As mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()) this method could throw a SQLiteException if the database cannot be opened for writing.

Also please enclose this method use in try/catch block so that it is easier to debug and fails gracefully without crashing the app.

Comment: essentially this is the answer. I was closing the db at the end of all the dbhandler functions but it was only being opened in the oncreate function.

Answer (score 0):

You might change your database, and in emulator it reads from old version. if you change database version(in your custom `SQLiteOpenHelper` class) then you might see that error in emulator too:

```
   super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
```

for example change DB_VERSION from 1 to 2.